# Simple example on how to continously scan qr/barcode with zxing

Tags: android, zxing

I need to build an app that continuously scans for QRs and barcode in a warehouse. For now I just need something like a SurfaceView in the background displaying the camera and a TextView to show the result of the last scanned QR/Barcode.

I've checked the official Zxing github repository and managed to build their sample app but it way to complex for what I need; stripping it down might be more difficult since I am just learning android.

I've already done a prototype of the app in Unity3D so I kind of know the API I need to solve the problem, I just need to get the camera displaying and a basic continuous scanning hello world. A working example would help me a lot.

Comment: @christian i remember doing it for one of my previous project..Post your sample code here so that we can help.

Comment: Thanks @Deva. I had some code which showed that camera on the background, but facing threads while you are learning is not a nice first experience, so I figured it would be best to start with some basic code by people who know more about Android.

Answer (score 0):

The basic underlying logic (if i recollect correct) was not to start your "ScanActivity" for result(or not to set the result back to the calling activity). This will ensure that you are always on the scan mode and you can decode result and display your success/failure for your scan result on the same screen.

Can detail it out more if you could post your ur sample (trial) snippet.